# Ensure filepath exists for reading

Tags: file, elisp

I need to define a function that will, without unnecessary side effects (i.e. an open buffer), ensure a file exists ready for reading.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(defun ensure-existence (file)
  (if (not (file-exists-p file))
    (kill-buffer
     (save-buffer
      (find-file-noselect file))))
```

which (seems to) work fine when the directory exists.  Unfortunately, I can't be sure that this is the case (since variables may change, etc.).  Is there any way to incorporate `make-directory` into all of this or, better yet, is there a cleaner solution?

My ideal use case would be something like this:

```
(ensure-existence "new/path/to/new/file.txt"
   (func1 arg1)
   (func2 arg2a arg2b)
   (...))
```

which would necessitate a signature like this:

```
(defun ensure-existence (file &rest body) ...)
```

but I don't really know how to do that. :/

---

This is all for <del>[a Stack Exchange mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/blob/feature/network/listing/stack-mode.org#prepare-favorites) for Emacs</del> new link: [`sx.el`](http://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el), by the way :-)

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand the signature `(file &rest body)` part; I suggest that you ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @sds Ummm... why?  `body` would be a list of everything after `file`.  Thus `(ensure-existence "foo.txt" (message "the file exists") (message "no, really, it does.  trust me."))` would set `file=>"foo.txt"` and `body=>'((message "...") (message "..."))` which can then be evaluated with `mapc` and `eval`.

Comment: `&body` is for macros, not functions.

Comment: @sds Oops, you're absolutely right; I meant `&rest`.  ;)

Comment: Then you should realise that all your `&rest` forms will be evaluated _before_ `ensure-existence` is actually called.

Comment: @sds not if you quote them

Comment: but then you will need to `eval` them and lose the bindings. Use either a closure or a macro; or, better yet, just use the function from my answer.

Comment: @sds I am using your answer; you can confirm with the repo :) but this goes into more of elisp/cl as languages. I'll look into closures some tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Stefan,

```
(defun ensure-file-exists (file)
  (unless (file-exist-p file)
    (make-directory (file-name-directory file) t)
    (write-region "" nil file nil 'silent)))
```

This should work on both windows and unix.

EDIT: actually, you can do away with the file existence check by passing the append `t` argument to [`write-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-to-Files.html), but this would change the modification time of the file if it already exists (just like [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html)).

Just for comparison, the Common Lisp version would look like this:

```
(defun ensure-file-exists (file &key verbose)
  (ensure-directories-exist foo :verbose verbose)
  (open file :direction :probe :if-does-not-exist :create))
```

(see [`open`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_open.htm) and [`ensure-file-exists`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ensu_1.htm)).

Comment: While everything is nice and dandy on UNIX systems, this wouldn't work on Windows.  Thanks though :)

Comment: Why use `touch` when you can use `(write-region "" nil <filename> nil 'silent)`.

Comment: [Thanks so much](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/blob/9c099b5305169249951ee989e17057192d742a70/stack-mode.org#prepare-favorites), @Stefan!

Comment: Just a minor point: If you want to ensure that the file is *readable*, as you said, then use **`file-readable-p`**, not `file-exists-p`.